# SUM со сложным условием

Tags: mysql, select

Есть таблица, а в ней такие столбцы:

```
price | trade_point_id | date
100   | 1              | 2019-01-01
112   | 1              | 2019-01-01
231   | 2              | 2019-01-02
180   | 2              | 2019-01-02
300   | 3              | 2019-01-03
10    | 3              | 2019-01-03
180   | 1              | 2019-01-04
800   | 1              | 2019-01-04
```

Мне нужно посчитать сумму в столбце price.
Так, чтобы суммировались те значения, которые имеют одинаковый trade_point_id и date.

То есть в результирующей таблице должно получиться:

```
sum   | trade_point_id | date
210   | 1              | 2019-01-01
411   | 2              | 2019-01-02
310   | 3              | 2019-01-03
980   | 1              | 2019-01-04
```

Никак не пойму, что написать в WHERE.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, используемый SQL-диалект в тегах с помощью кнопки "править"

Comment: нужна группировка `GROUP BY`. `SELECT SUM(price), trade_point_id, date FROM ТАБЛИЦА GROUP BY trade_point_id, date`. вообще все агрегирующие функции требуют `GROUP BY`

Comment: @cppquestions похоже на SQLite

Comment: @TotalPusher хм, как вы это узнали? В вопросе я вижу только структуры таблиц. Думаете, даты представлены строками? В любом случае, можете предложить соответствующую правку, если ТС её не сделает

Comment: Разобралась. Сделала с помощью GORUP BY. 

SELECT SUM(`purchase`.`price`), `purchase`.`trade_point_id`, `purchase`.`date` FROM `purchase` 
GROUP BY `purchase`.`date`, `purchase`.`trade_point_id`;

Спасибо!

Comment: @cppquestions это всего лишь предположение, основанное на том, как выводит SQLite результаты выборки. Ну и диалект SQL тут не важен

Comment: Извините, я абы-как таблицы вывела. Это MySQL

Comment: *не пойму, что написать в WHERE.* Эта секция вообще не нужна.